# Running GameJS in NW.js or Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, nw.js

I want to run gamejs (gamejs.org) just like I might on the browser, but instead in the "browser" of either nodewebkit, or electron.

The example of including the game.js downloadable from the gamejs site says I basically need to include the script and then "require" it (using yabble code or something that's been included in gamejs.js)

Like so:

```
<script type="text/javacript" src="gamejs.js"></script>
<script>
    var gamejs = require("gamejs");
</script>
```

But, I get that synchronous require is not supported by game.js in nodewebkit, and gamejs is undefined in electron.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Install gamejs with the npm module manager.

```
npm install gamejs
```

The require should look like this:

```
var gamejs = require("gamejs");
```

You don't need the following

```
<script type="text/javacript" src="gamejs.js"></script>
```